# What does (new Class())->Function(); mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax

I have seen this form in the blog of one of the employees of MS. But what does it mean? I'm confused because he **didn't delete** after using the new operator. Is that completely legal? Or it can only be used in Visual C++?

Source code from his blog:

```
(new RegForm())->ShowMaximized();
GetApplication()->Run();
```

Comment: It's valid C++, but could be a potential leak. Or it's possible that the `RegForm` instance is supposed to live for the entire duration of the program and he chose to write it this way. Cannot say more without more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly it's legal to `new` things and not delete them. It may cause a memory leak but that is permitted in C++.

In this specific piece of code, `new` generates a pointer to an object. You can use `->` on a pointer to call a member function of the object, so this creates the RegForm and then calls `ShowMaximized` on it.

We can't tell from this code whether or not there is a memory leak. However RegForm might be using a sort of self-registration pattern. For example its constructor might contain:

```
GlobalListOfObjectsToDeleteLater.push_back(this);
```

and when the application shuts down , another piece of code will go through the list deleting everything.

In fact, it seems likely that RegForm registers itself with some other part of the GUI , it would have to do that in order to be able to Show itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly same as

```
RegForm* pForm = new RegForm();
pForm->ShowMaximized();
```

There is no tight and strict rule that saying delete all `new`s before end the programe. programmer should know what he do and avoid memory leaks (specially in repetitive task). by the way all the memory will be clean when the application `exit`.